# Updating ResourceDictionary using Resources.BeginInit()

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary, mergeddictionaries

I am updating Resources (merging dictionaries and changing ResourceKey values) in code behind. I read somewhere that I should write all ResourceDictionary changes between these lines `Resources.BeginInit()` and `Resources.EndInit()` that ways DynamicResources are not applied until all changes are done.

Can anyone provide more clarification on what happens when a Resource is added/removed from merged dictionaries are when a Resource key is updated?

Example:

```
    private void _replaceResourceDictionary(ResourceDictionary newResource, ResourceDictionary oldResource)
    {
         double newDefaultFontSize = 15.0;

        //This info may be incorrect: Using Begin & End ensures that DynamicResources are not refresh multiple times
        Application.Current.Resources.BeginInit();
        _removeFromMergedDictionaries(oldResource);
        _addToMergedDictionaries(newResource);
        Application.Current.Resources.EndInit();

       //Question: Does using Begin & End will benefit here as well?
        Application.Current.Resources.BeginInit();
        Application.Current.Resources["FontSize_Small"] = newDefaultFontSize - 2;
        Application.Current.Resources["FontSize_Default"] = newDefaultFontSize;
        Application.Current.Resources["FontSize_DefaultPlus"] = newDefaultFontSize + 2;
        Application.Current.Resources["FontSize_HeaderNormal"] = newDefaultFontSize + 4;
        Application.Current.Resources["FontSize_HeaderLarge"] = newDefaultFontSize + 6;
        Application.Current.Resources["FontSize_MenuItem"] = newDefaultFontSize + 12;
        Application.Current.Resources.EndInit();
    }
```

Thanks,

RDV

Comment: I think you should rethink your entire approach. Have a default RD and then load another RD with the new values in (and same keys). This idea of loading new dictionaries and then also manipulating the values in code like you are here is kinda missing the point of dynamically loading RD in the first place.

Comment: this is just an example, i am not doing both the things at the same time. I have another question for what you pointed out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54428306/wpf-performance-impact-resourcedictionary-merging-vs-updating